# Can my ISP see what sites I visit if I use a private DNS provider?

Tags: anonymity

In order to browse anonymously, I use SOCKS proxies, flush cookies and cache, and pay for a private DNS service.

Sometimes, I need to browse without using all of those, but I keep my private DNS service turned on.

Can my ISP track exactly what sites and pages I visit?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your ISP can see what websites you are visiting. They can do this whether the sites are using HTTPS or not. They can do this whether you use their DNS servers or not. And they can link these to a specific account. Basically, your data is going over their network, and they need to route it to the correct location. All an alternative DNS provider offers is a different lookup between a domain name and an IP address - the IP data still goes through your ISP, along with your request headers, which have to include the domain name (although no specific URLs).

They can't do it if you use a VPN or TOR - both of these would show as a single connection to a different computer. They could still see how much data you were sending and receiving, although there are ways to hide that too. However, the VPN provider would be able to see what sites you were connecting to, as would a TOR exit node provider. In the case of a VPN provider, this might be linked to a specific account, or source IP, in a way that could be tracked - you have to trust them. In the case of TOR, the exit node shouldn't be able to link data back to a specific source IP.

Comment: Can you elaborate how "VPN could still see how much data you were sending and receiving, although there are ways to hide that too." What are the ways to to hide the relevant information?

Comment: By padding out your communication with lots of irrelevant stuff.  This could be automated if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Simon, could you send me a link or any other source of information for understanding what is the automated way to pad the communication with irrelevant stuff?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is able to track your DNS query log **and** website list, sometimes it can track some additional tokens or unencrypted data. The problem of tracking is that in this particular case it's very important to keep the tracking action under the hood, so it's a split-case sceinario :

- **unencrypted/telnet-like traffic/protocols** A regular `tcpdump` utility or it's clones like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) can *just copy-on-flight* every packet that passes through a network line. 100% stealth function can be achieved even by a school kid in this case. And - unencrypted communications are just plaint(text), so : dump it and read/parse/systematize as you wish. No comments
- **IP address hunting** A common practice for russian goverment criminals to censor the Internet. They can *just close all slideshare.net* for example, just using that technique : this was the most recent case, actually. It is performed via DPI/DSI packet analysis. You can use **encrypted** channel like HTTPS/TLS, but on OSI Layer 2 your packets are **unprotected** : they're *plainly routed* directly to the target. If not hijacked, then your traffic will be "fingerprintted" as in previous case. To fight this you should use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) or [I2P](https://geti2p.net/en/) to make your *network routemap cryptographically protected*, basically speaking.
- **SSL/TLS Man-in-the-Middle** Our trust to CA's is a *legacy habbit*. An ISP can substitute certificates "on-the-fly" and turn your protected traffic to unprotected one to deal with it like first case. Use [Project Perspectives](http://perspectives-project.org) to utilize an *independent* certificate checking ability, [Calomel SSL Validation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/calomel-ssl-validation/) to see if there's a weak crypto(it can be either a loosy server security or a sign of a spoofed certificate : to generate lots of fake certs ISP will need too many resources, so it would use a weak certs that are faster to create/generate) and [Certificate Patrol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/?src=ss) to *actually see* what's going on behind the curtains

Feel free to ask more questions, and you can take a look at my own [Tor guide](http://crowdcourse.net/ru/tor_setup_howto). it's currently work-in-progress, russian version is there, english translation will be as soon as I'll have time for this.

Comment: I think this answer would be stronger if you expanded on the 'sometimes it can track' part

Comment: @NeilSmithline take a look at my update, feel free to ask more info if you need it